# Build failing after adding a test, eventhough there are no errors in the script.Using selenium,testng with maven in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, testng

I have a maven module which has an a.b.c package and there is a test AssetUploadTest.java and one more test NavigateToPage.java. I am getting a build error only when I am adding the AssetUploadTest. I don't want the tests to run but just be compiled, because I have a properties file which has a username and pwd to my website. But due to compliance, we should not upload the username and pwd into our git. So I gave replace-with-username and replace-with-pwd.
My problem is why the build is successful when here is the second test, and why it is failing with the other test. 
This is the error trace

```
INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  34.047 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-20T17:34:43-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project aem-microsoft-martech.it.tests: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\v-sruga\git\AxeCore\CSM-CASM-CoMgmt-Nabu-AEM\it.tests\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com.micrososft.mcb.tests.ui.AssetUploadTest
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com.micrososft.mcb.tests.ui.AssetUploadTest
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:665)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:279)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:243)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1077)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:907)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:785)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Please help me. I tried to change the surefire version,failsafe version, but no luck.

My pom looks like this


    <properties>
        <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
    <!--  <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory> -->
           <!--  <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/test</testSourceDirectory> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Sling-Test-Regexp>.*Test</Sling-Test-Regexp>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>run-all-tests.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.cmpn</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- TODO create separate API package, this is just to get the special 
                Sling test runner -->
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.junit.core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.org.lidalia</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>{project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>aem-microsoft-martech.core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>bundle</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
            <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
            <classifier>apis</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

No sufficient Code ,So i guess :

The class in  your code  is `a.b.c. AssetUploadTest`!

But from StackTrace we can see this line ,`Cannot find class in classpath: com.micrososft.mcb.tests.ui.AssetUploadTest`,which indicates that you import  `com.micrososft.mcb.tests.ui.AssetUploadTest` in fact!

The maven can't find the class in classpath and Build failing.

Comment: The package is com.microsoft.mcb.tests.ui.AssetUploadTest only

Comment: There is some problem with my testng.xml file. I have mentioned <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"> instead of <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">... Now it is working fine.

Comment: congratulation to get the resoluiton!